# SQL select statement headings

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Having trouble working out how to do headings

Display the total number of FEMALE students under the heading 'FEMALE STUDENTS':

Struture:

```
CREATE TABLE Student

    (StudID       INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
     StudFName    VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
     StudLName    VARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL,
     DoB          DATE          NOT NULL,
     Sex          CHAR(1)       NOT NULL CHECK (Sex IN ('M', 'F')),
     Email        VARCHAR(30)   UNIQUE);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT count(Sex) as "FEMALE STUDENTS"
from Student
where sex='F';
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also try the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Total Students"
     , SUM(DECODE(sex, 'F', 1, 0)) AS "Female Students"
     , SUM(DECODE(sex, 'F', 0, 1)) AS "Male Students"
  FROM students
```

I use this method often to get multiple counts as part of one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use count() function to retrieve the number of rows under a particular column.

Syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(column_name) FROM  table_name;
```

In your case the query would be:

```
SELECT count(sex) from Student where sex='F';
```

COUNT returns the number of rows returned by the query. You can use it as an aggregate or analytic function.

For more info:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions032.htm

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: There is no reason to use `COUNT(sex)` here over `COUNT(*)`